# Create Public Endpoint for Wordpress API

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am getting a 401 Unauthorized error when I try to access a public endpoint I made, through POSTMAN. 
[image]
[image]

Though, if I log into the wp-admin and access it via Browser, it works fine.

[image]

I already added '__return_true' as the permission callback, as the WP API Handbook suggested, but it still does not work when accessed publicly.

[image]

How do I make the API endpoint public/accessible to anonymous users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling plugins for the site, and it turns out a plugin called "password protect" causing this error.